# xev doesn't record keycode of lock screen key

Tags: keyboard, xev, keycodes

I just got a lenovo ideapad 720s and installed Ubuntu. It has no media control keys (play/pause, next/prev track), so I wanted to remap some keys I don't use including the lock screen key. But when I use `xev` and press the key, the screen locks and the keycode is not displayed in the terminal. Is there another way to find the keycode?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `xinput`
List 'devices': run `xinput` with no argument

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

'Spy' the extra buttons

```
xinput test 12
```

Comment: Same issue, it works for the other keys but when I press the lock key it just locks the computer and doesn't record the keycode

Comment: you may try another id...

Comment: Tried em all. I might need to just remap random keycodes till I find the right one :)